# .ttf files being applied to website

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

So I have these fonts that we are using.  They are Futura-CondensedBold.ttf, Futura-CondensedMedium.ttf, Futura-Medium.ttf, Futura-MediumItalic.ttf.  I actually have the files for these fonts.  We need to use these on our web site.  Now i know how to link fonts from say Google, or typekit as many sites i have created use these.  But how do I get the user to download the fonts from this site I am creating since i have the actual font files?  I assume i need to create a folder, which i will do in my CSS directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a **@font-face** call to those files in your CSS. I usually throw a "fonts" folder in the assets folder and host the files there. Then just point the font-face src urls to the location of each filetype in that font's folder.

```css
@font-face {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-family: "FONT NAME";
 src: url("../fonts/FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼.eot");
 src: url("../fonts/￼FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼￼￼￼.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
   url("../fonts/￼FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼￼￼.svg#SVGFONTNAME") format("svg"),
   url("../fonts/￼FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼￼￼.woff2") format("woff2"),
   url("../fonts/￼FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼￼￼.woff") format("woff"),
   url("../fonts/￼FAMILY/FONT-NAME￼￼￼￼.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

I hope that answers your question.